# How to change mouse cursor on mac using Python?

Tags: python, macos, mouse-cursor

I want to change the mouse cursor to a laser pointer when someone clicks on a button using python script. How to do it on MAC?

In windows I have done like this to do the same

```
hnew = win32gui.LoadImage(0,  resource_path('laser.cur'), win32con.IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE)
ctypes.windll.user32.SetSystemCursor(hnew, 32512)
```

But it is not supported on mac as it is window specific library.

Answer (score 0):

You need access to the Cocoa frameworks which seems possible with this [library](https://pypi.org/project/PyCocoa/) (not tested). Within Cocoa the object to call is [NSCursor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscursor?language=objc). In Objective-c you set the cursor like this :

```
[NSCursor.arrowCursor set]
```

You can also use a pair of command to change the cursor and reset it after the action :

```
[NSCursor.pointingHandCursor push]
// Do an action
[NSCursor pop]
```

To create a custom cursor, you use a NSImage you create from a path (here I do it with a pdf image to support high resolution screen) :

```
NSString * pathToAnImage = "A/B/C.pdf"
NSImage * image = [NSImage multiRepresentationImageFromPDF: pathToAnImage withMaxScaleFactor:4];
NSPoint hotSpot = NSMakePoint(8, 8); //the relative position within the image interpreted as the cursor location

NSCursor * customCursor = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage:image hotSpot:hotSpot]]
```

Then you can use it as any other system cursor.

Comment: That will allow me to replace the mouse cursor with a custom laser cursor?